# difference between these two function

Tags: typescript

```
for(let i:number = 0 ;i<n;i++){
let sectionLine : any = sectionList[i];>>>>1
let sectionLine : SectionLine ={...sectionList[i]};>>>>2
```

what is the difference between 1 and 2?
is let it as any or SectionLine influence the efficiency of the program?

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency no, Any and SectionLine as used in your code sample is to ensure that the type of values assigned to the variables you are defining are of the right type eg any and SectionLine. It is not an ionic thing par say but typescript to  provides static typing.

Comment: is sectionList[i] different from {...sectionList[i]} in efficiency?

Comment: {...sectionLisit[i]} will copy every enumerable property of the object at the array index i into a new object. given the size of the object at the array index the copy operation might be expensive.
Note: I assumed that the value at the array index "i" is an object